# How to calculate(add) values of Child

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm new to firebase, So I don't know much about the firebase methods but I  would like to sum values of "total" of every child and store them in a variable.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref(); 
var rootreq = rootRef.child("Requests"); 
rootreq.on('value',getReq); 
function getReq(snap){ 
    snap.forEach(keyReq => { 
        var total = keyReq.val().total; 
        var t = parseInt(total); 
        var t1 = t + total; 
        $("#tr_count").valueOf(t1); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried

Comment: <script>
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var rootreq = rootRef.child("Requests");
  rootreq.on('value',getReq);
   function getReq(snap){
      snap.forEach(keyReq => {     
       var total  = keyReq.val().total;
       var t = parseInt(total);
       var t1 = t + total;
       $("#tr_count").valueOf(t1);
      });
   } </script> @RosárioPereiraFernandes , Thank you sir, for looking at my problem

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You just need to declare the variable that will contain the total outside of the `forEach` loop:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref(); 
var rootreq = rootRef.child("Requests"); 
rootreq.on('value',getReq); 
function getReq(snap){ 
    var t1 = 0;
    snap.forEach(keyReq => { 
        var total = keyReq.val().total; 
        var t = parseInt(total); 
        t1 += t; 
    }); 
    $("#tr_count").valueOf(t1); 
}
```

Let me also point out that this downloads the whole Requests node to the user device, and this is bad for app performance. I recommend creating an outer node that contains the total of Requests and maybe using a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to [increment this counter](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count).

Comment: I'm getting a undefined symbol if i put total outside of forEach loop & running out of thinking , If you can help out with CODE it would be greatfull for me SIR @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: The sum is stored under `t1` ... the `total` variable is just auxiliary (temporary). Why do you need it outside of the `forEach` loop?

Comment: then how can i calculate Total amount of all orders, Sir @RosárioPereiraFernandes  ?

Comment: My code calculates it and stores it in the `t1` variable.  Where do you want to display the result?

Comment: I want to display in Web Page (Dashboard)

Comment: I want to display in Web Page (Dashboard.php)  
<div class="inner"><h3 id="tr_count"> </h3><script>
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref(); 
var rootreq = rootRef.child("Requests"); 
rootreq.on('value',getReq); 
function getReq(snap){ var t1 = 0;  snap.forEach(keyReq => { 
 var total = keyReq.val().total; 
 var t = parseInt(total);  t1 += t; }); 
$("#tr_count").valueOf(t1);  } 
</script></div>
@Rosário Pereira Fernandes

Comment: Rosário Pereira Fernandes do you get any solution to it

Comment: What's `tr_count` ?

Comment: it the element tag where i need to display the total amount count

Comment: I understand, but which element? Try using `$("#tr_count").val(t1);` or `$("#tr_count").html(t1);` or even `$("#tr_count").text(t1);`

Comment: By using $("#tr_count").text(t1); it displaying the "NaN" output and rest of it is not working

Comment: Please make sure you're using the code from my answer and not the code from your question